# wbadmin command can't run from windows service

Tags: c#, service, console

```
string path = "D:";
string wbadminPath = Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\wbadmin";
string wbadminEvent = "start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:" + path + " -quiet";

        try
        {
            int exitCode = 0;
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(wbadminPath, wbadminEvent);
            using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                exitCode = proc.ExitCode;                    
            }
        }
```

If I execute this code in Console Application, - It works.
If I execute this code in Windows Service I have this error:

*Command Line Interface for Microsoft BLB Backup has stopped working*

*Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: wbadmin.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.6001.18000
  Application Timestamp:    47918aed
  Fault Module Name:    kernel32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.18327
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4cb73436
  Exception Code:   c0000142
  Exception Offset: 00009f7d
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9d13
  Additional Information 2: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
  Additional Information 3: 9d13
  Additional Information 4: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I know I'm to late to be of help, but hopefully someone else will benefit from this.

Windows Services cannot interact with anything with a GUI or that requires user interaction. Basically when you call `Process.Start(start)` it tries to open the CMD window which a service can't do. You can use something like:

```
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            start.CreateNoWindow = true;//This stops the GUI
```

HOWEVER it is worth noting I tried for hours to get this particular command to work and could not. I ended up scrapping the entire idea after hours of work and research. In general you can run CMD commands from a service using the .CreateNoWindow, however it does not seem to work in this case (it fails to find the WBADMIN process). If I find anythign new on this in the future I will update.

Here's a thread talking about [why services can't access GUIs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180833/why-cant-windows-services-have-a-gui) anymore

Comment: This is true you can't use GUI in the service and it's a good idea not to. In case you really really have to, there is a workaround.
Instead of creating your service in C# as you would, set the project to the standard command line, then register it as a service with NSSM (non-suckicng service manager) - it's an open source utility that can convert any application to Windows Service.